# R ggiraph with ggmap for interactive/reactive longitude and latitude points - scale or axis issue?

Tags: r, ggplot2, interactive, ggmap, ggiraph

The new **ggiraph** package is really great for making ggplot2 reactive to users' mouse, no problems.

However **I'm having trouble getting this to work properly with ggmap() for interactive/reactive longitude and latitude points**.

The interactivity works fine, I can get tooltip response when the mouse is hovered a point, but there seems to be a problem with the scale or axis when using it with ggmap().

**The code chunks below provide a reproducible example of the problem** that I am trying to solve, and there are also some images linked to illustrate what I mean.

First *install required packages*, then make up small *example data set*, and then *download required map* using get_map() function:

```
#Install required_packages:
required_packages <- c("ggmap", "ggplot2", "ggiraph")
new.packages <- required_packages[!(required_packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
#Load required_packages:
lapply(required_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

#Make small example data set:
suburb<-c("BURNLEY","COLLINGWOOD","MALVERN","PRAHRAN","RICHMOND","SOUTH YARRA","ST KILDA","ST KILDA WEST","TOORAK","WINDSOR")
lon<-c(145.0176466,144.98815,145.036,144.998,144.998,144.989,144.982,144.9732,145.018,144.988)
lat<-c(-37.8299258, -37.8019,-37.857,-37.852,-37.823,-37.84,-37.864,-37.8604,-37.841,-37.854)
`Change 2005-2015 (%)`<-c(112, 120, 136, 127, 122, 115, 110, 146, 120, 128)
df<-data.frame(suburb, lon, lat, `Change 2005-2015 (%)`)

#Download map from google maps
SOUTH_YARRA <- get_map(location = 'South Yarra, Australia', zoom = 13, maptype="terrain")
```

Now I have no problem using the code below to create the static map:

```
ggmap(SOUTH_YARRA) + 
    geom_point(data = df, 
               aes(x =lon, y= lat, size=`Change 2005-2015 (%)`, colour = `Change 2005-2015 (%)`),
               alpha=0.75) +  
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(5)) +
    scale_radius (range = c(6, 12), trans = "identity", guide = "legend") +
    ggtitle("Total change in Median \n House Price (%) from 2005-2015 \n")
```

[here is the static map produced by the code above - no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOsZq.png)

However, when I use ggiraph's geom_point_interactive() to make the points in the map react to the user's mouse hover, a problem with the scale or axis occurs:

```
#Try add reactivity using ggiraph's geom_point_interactive() instead of geom_point()
interactive_map<-ggmap(SOUTH_YARRA) + 
    geom_point_interactive(data = df, 
                           aes(x =lon, y= lat, size=`Change 2005-2015 (%)`, colour = `Change 2005-2015 (%)`, tooltip=suburb, data_id = suburb),
                           alpha=0.75) +  
    scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(5)) +
    scale_radius (range = c(6, 12), trans = "identity", guide = "legend") +
    ggtitle("Total change in Median Melbourne \n House Price (%) from 2005-2015 \n")

ggiraph(code = {print(interactive_map)}, zoom_max = 5,
        tooltip_offx = 20, tooltip_offy = -10, 
        hover_css = "fill:black;",
        tooltip_opacity = 0.7)
```

[here is a still image of my scale/axis problem produced by the code above. Note the the code above makes the tooltip reactivity works fine for mouse hover, it's just this scale problem that I need to resolve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHOaM.png)

I've tried changing the maprange, extent, and base_layer arguments to the ggmap() function, e.g.:

```
ggmap(SOUTH_YARRA, maprange=TRUE, extent = "panel", base_layer = ggplot(data = df, aes(x =lon, y= lat)))
```

However this hase not helped. ggiraph is an awesome package imho, since it is new there are not yet much on stackoverflow etc for it. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: p.s. Also, I am aware of the geom_map_interactive() function in ggiraph, it is really nice, however I need to use ggmap() with geom_point_interactive(), if I could just solve this scale problem it would be perfect

Comment: UPDATE:  This has been logged as a bug on package github repo,  package author says " it seems there is an issue with raster objects"  https://github.com/davidgohel/ggiraph/issues/32

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you might want to look at the `viridis` color scales instead of that rainbow palette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the ggiraph package, and the package maintainer has just fixed it, see the github bug report here for more details: https://github.com/davidgohel/ggiraph/issues/32#issuecomment-257869888